# How to mock a argument pass to the method + minitest

Tags: minitest

I'm working on a test case wherein I want to check the integrity of the argument pass to the method.

Here how my controller code looks like.

```
 def show
    response = begin
      site = Site.find_by(id: params[:id])
      site.bonsai_site_configuration
    rescue StandardError => exception
      ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(exception)
      {}
    end
    render json: response, status: 200
  end
```

Now, all I want to ensure that when I mock the `find_by` and to return `site` object I need the argument to match exactly what I intend it to be.
over here `{id: site.id}`

This is how my test currently looks like. I'm not very much familiar with minitest so would request you to please have patience with me. As I'm not entirely sure if the below code(test) is the correct way to write a minitest test.

```
 test 'Services::SiteController: Show: Return `{}` as Site configuration on error' do
    mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :call, true, [RuntimeError]

    site = Site.first

    site_mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    site_mock.expect :call, site, [{id: site.id}]

    raises_exception = Proc.new { raise 'boom' }

    Site.stub(:find_by, site_mock) do
      site.stub(:bonsai_site_configuration, raises_exception) do
        ExceptionNotifier.stub(:notify_exception, mock) do
          get "/switch/sites/#{site.id}",
            headers: { Authorization: "Basic b2576d705c208c19fd1601ef58aa0506bd4e2e93c51c19df856483cbbfc7cb67" }
          response = JSON.parse(@response.body)
          assert_successful_response
          assert_empty(response)
        end
      end
    end
    assert_mock site_mock
    assert_mock mock
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are 2 ways to test this.

Firstly, I was correct the

`site_mock.expect :call, site, [{id: site.id}]`

is the correct way to test this behaviour all I needed to change is.

`site_mock.expect :call, site, [{id: site.id.to_s}]`

The other way to test this is.

```
site_mock.expect :call, site do |*args|
  args[0][:id] == site.id
end
```